# What happens when you use string interpolation in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I thought that ruby just call method to_s but I can't explain how this works:

```ruby
class Fake
  def to_s
    self
  end
end

"#{Fake.new}"
```

By the logic this should raise stack level too deep because of infinity recursion. But it works fine and seems to call #to_s from an Object.

```
=> "#<Fake:0x137029f8>"
```

But why?

**ADDED:**

```
class Fake
  def to_s
    Fake2.new
  end
end

class Fake2
  def to_s
    "Fake2#to_s"
  end
end
```

This code works differently in two cases:

```
puts "#{Fake.new}" => "#<Fake:0x137d5ac4>"
```

But:

```
puts Fake.new.to_s => "Fake2#to_s"
```

I think it's abnormal. Can somebody suggest when in ruby interpreter it happens internally?

Comment: FYI, if you `def to_s; "#{self}"; end` then you *do* get `stack level too deep`. `def to_s; self; end` is not recursive though.

Comment: You are mixing two different things in your "Added section"

you are just modifying the to_s of Fake class by ouputing the sentence "Fake2#to_s" using another class who have a name close to the first one.


I think you should try to understand more about how object oriented work.

Comment: My question is not about OO but about ruby internals - what happens in string interpolation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Short version

Ruby does call `to_s`, but it checks that `to_s` returns a string. If it doesn't, ruby calls the default implementation of `to_s` instead. Calling `to_s` recursively wouldn't be a good idea (no guarantee of termination) - you could crash the VM and ruby code shouldn't be able to crash the whole VM.

You get different output from `Fake.new.to_s` because irb calls `inspect` to display the result to you, and `inspect` calls `to_s` a second time

### Long version

To answer "what happens when ruby does x", a good place to start is to look at what instructions get generated for the VM (this is all MRI specific). For your example:

```
puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile('"#{Foo.new}"').disasm
```

outputs

```
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 getinlinecache   9, <is:0>
0005 getconstant      :Foo
0007 setinlinecache   <is:0>
0009 opt_send_simple  <callinfo!mid:new, argc:0, ARGS_SKIP>
0011 tostring         
0012 concatstrings    1
0014 leave
```

There's some messing around with the cache, and you'll always get `trace`, `leave` but in a nutshell this says.

1. get the constant Foo
2. call its new method
3. execute the tostring instruction
4. execute the concatstrings instruction with the result of the tostring instruction (the  last value on the stack (if you do this with multiple #{} sequences you can see it building up all the individual strings and then calling concatstrings once on all consuming all of those strings)

The instructions in this dump are defined in [insns.def](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/insns.def#L384): this maps these instructions to their implementation. You can see that `tostring` just calls `rb_obj_as_string`.

If you search for `rb_obj_as_string` through the ruby codebase (I find http://rxr.whitequark.org useful for this) you can see it's defined [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/string.c#L1011) as

```
VALUE
rb_obj_as_string(VALUE obj)
{
    VALUE str;

    if (RB_TYPE_P(obj, T_STRING)) {
    return obj;
    }
    str = rb_funcall(obj, id_to_s, 0);
    if (!RB_TYPE_P(str, T_STRING))
    return rb_any_to_s(obj);
    if (OBJ_TAINTED(obj)) OBJ_TAINT(str);
    return str;
}
```

In brief, if we already have a string then return that. If not, call the object's `to_s` method. Then, (and this is what is crucial for your question), it checks the type of the result. If it's not a string it returns `rb_any_to_s` instead, which is the function that implements the default `to_s`

Comment: Good answer. To see this behavior with a simple example: `class D; def to_s; Object.new; end; end; puts "#{D.new}"; puts D.new.to_s`.  Note that printing `"#{D.new}"` prints info about a `D` and not about an `Object`